# spring cloud contract - Wiremock Bad <init> method call from inside of a branch Exception Details

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have a producer which is:
springboot - 1.5.1.RELEASE
springcloudVersion = 'Camden.SR5'
Has classpath ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE")
testCompile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier')

I can successfully run the build on producer and can see the generated contracts.

Now,

I have a consumer which is
springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RC1'
Has
testCompile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner")
testCompile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier")

I have a simple contract test like this:

```
@Rule
public StubRunnerRule rule = new StubRunnerRule()
        .downloadStub("groupid", "artifact")
        .stubsMode(StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL);

@Test
public void testValidALPEndpoint() {
    String output = runEndpointCheck("ac01");
    assertEquals("test", output);    }

@Test
public void testInvalidALPEndpoint() {
    String output = runEndpointCheck("invalid");
    assertNotEquals("invalid", output);
}

private String runEndpointCheck(String urlPath) {
    URL url = this.rule.findStubUrl("groupid", "artifact"");
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + "/" + urlPath);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("HTTP client failed to open", e);
    }
}
```

It is able to locate the stub jar from local m2 repo.

But then it error out with

```
    org/springframework/cloud/contract/verifier/dsl/wiremock/DefaultResponseTransformer.<init>(ZLjava/lang/String;Lwiremock/com/github/jknack/handlebars/Helper;)V @108: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b800 133a 0406 bd00 4059 031b b800 4653
    0x0000010: 5904 2c53 5905 2d53 5910 ff12 04b8 004a
    0x0000020: 2a5f ab00 0000 00a4 0000 0004 9db7 bd78
    0x0000030: 0000 002a 0013 85ff 0000 0050 15b4 0b91
    0x0000040: 0000 0060 286f b7a6 0000 0088 5f5a 5903
    0x0000050: 32b8 0050 5f59 0432 b800 56c0 0058 5f59
    0x0000060: 0532 125a b800 28c0 005a 5f57 b700 5ca7
    0x0000070: 0061 5f5a 5903 32b8 0050 5f57 b700 3ca7
    0x0000080: 0051 5f5a 5903 32b8 0050 5f59 0432 125e
    0x0000090: b800 28c0 005e 5f59 0532 1222 b800 28c0
    0x00000a0: 0022 5f57 b700 61a7 0029 5f5a 5903 32b8
    0x00000b0: 0050 5f59 0432 1222 b800 28c0 0022 5f57
    0x00000c0: b700 2ba7 000d bb00 6359 1265 b700 68bf
    0x00000d0: 572a b600 333a 0519 052a 5fb5 0035 1905
    0x00000e0: 57b1                                   
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@76,{UninitializedThis,Integer,Object[#88],Object[#90],Object[#57]},{Object[#110],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@114,{UninitializedThis,Integer,Object[#88],Object[#90],Object[#57]},{Object[#110],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@130,{UninitializedThis,Integer,Object[#88],Object[#90],Object[#57]},{Object[#110],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@170,{UninitializedThis,Integer,Object[#88],Object[#90],Object[#57]},{Object[#110],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@198,{UninitializedThis,Integer,Object[#88],Object[#90],Object[#57]},{Object[#110],UninitializedThis})
    full_frame(@208,{Object[#2],Integer,Object[#88],Object[#90],Object[#57]},{Object[#110]})


    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.provider.wiremock.WireMockHttpServerStub.responseTransformers(WireMockHttpServerStub.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.provider.wiremock.WireMockHttpServerStub.config(WireMockHttpServerStub.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.provider.wiremock.WireMockHttpServerStub.start(WireMockHttpServerStub.java:107)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubServer.start(StubServer.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor$1.call(StubRunnerExecutor.java:260)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor$1.call(StubRunnerExecutor.java:256)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AvailablePortScanner.executeLogicForAvailablePort(AvailablePortScanner.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AvailablePortScanner.tryToExecuteWithFreePort(AvailablePortScanner.java:63)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.startStubServers(StubRunnerExecutor.java:256)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerExecutor.runStubs(StubRunnerExecutor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunner.runStubs(StubRunner.java:72)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner.runStubs(BatchStubRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.junit.StubRunnerRule$1.before(StubRunnerRule.java:69)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.junit.StubRunnerRule$1.evaluate(StubRunnerRule.java:62)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an ancient release train. Also most likely you have a mismatch of dependencies. Most likely there's a problem with WireMock versions. It would be best if you upgraded the release train versions and check again.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Do you mean, I should update the versions on Producer side? I dont have the access to that codebase, so I cant update it.

Comment: Bunp from camden to edgware.sr3 and try again

Comment: I just forked the producer and updated the bootversion to Edgeware.sr3. But I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you upload your sample somewhere? It looks as if you had either library mismatch or Java mismatch

Comment: Its a commercial app, so I cant upload it but will see if I can write something similar and reproduce the issue. But in the meantime, I checked the dependencies on the consumer side and I can see   +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:2.0.0.RC1
|    |    +--- com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.17.0. There is only 1 version of wiremock-standalone. And here are the java details:$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose its a JAVA version issue. Had to add jvmargs -noverify to bootrun and tests for supressing it.
Works ok now.
Will keep looking for the compatible JDK version to fix this issue without involving -noverify